# Use buttons to update XML element styled with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

As a newbie to XSL, minimal exposure to XML, I'm having trouble figuring out how to integrate the two with HTML. I'd like to use two buttons to update two elements captured in an XML document and have it update the elements displayed using the XSL stylesheet. I've provided snippets of the code below.

XML

```
<best_answer>
<head>
   <title>Title text goes here </title>
  <objective>
     <goal>Goal text goes here</goal>
  </objective>

  <settings>
       <setting type="Application">App Name</setting>
  </settings>

<verifications>
   <verification type="Helpful">10</verification>
   <verification type="Unhelpful">5</verification>
</verifications> 
</head>
</best_answer>
```

XSL

```
  <xsl:template match="verifications">
  <br></br>
  <table style="border:1px dashed; align: center; border-spacing: 5px; width: 100%">
 <tr colspan="2">
   <td >Was this topic helpful?</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td style="padding-left:20px;">
     <button id="yes" type="button">Yes</button>
   </td>

   <td style="padding-left:30px;">
     <button id="no" type="button">No</button>
   </td>
 </tr>

 <tr></tr>
 <tr></tr>

 <tr>
   <xsl:for-each select="verification">
     <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="@type='Helpful'">
         <td>
           <img src="image.png" height="12" width="16">
           </img>
            &#160;<xsl:value-of select="@type"/>: 
           <xsl:value-of select="text()"/><xsl:text></xsl:text> 
         </td>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
         <img src="image2.png" height="12" width="16">
         </img>
         &#160;<xsl:value-of select="@type"/>: 
         <xsl:value-of select="text()"/><xsl:text></xsl:text> 
       </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>                  

   </xsl:for-each>
   </tr>
</table>

</xsl:template>
```

I'd like to have the "Yes" button update the Verification text where the type equals "Helpful" and have the "No" button update the Verification text where the type equals "Unhelpful". So for example, if the user clicks the "Yes" button, the text captured in the Verification element with a type "Helpful" should increment by one. Likewise, if the user clicks the "No" button, the text captured in the Verification element with a type of "Unhelpful" should increment by one.

Hope that makes sense...Any help that can be provided is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If by "update" you mean modify the original XML document, that's not possible. At least not when using XSLT in a browser to display XML as HTML.

Comment: Michael is true, you can't natively use XSLT to interactively modify your HTML page. But you have products, like Saxon CE (openSource) http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml, wich permit it. Check it, you should find what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k for the quick response! I forgot that I'm displaying the XML file, and not an HTML file. I was more interested in updating the content that displays on the page, not the actual XML document. However, I assume (based on your explanation) that because the XML document is what's being displayed and formatted using CSS and XSLT, then what I'm trying to do isn't actual possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, @EricS. I'll check it out to see if that's what I need.

Comment: "*I forgot that I'm displaying the XML file, and not an HTML file.*" That's not quite correct. You are displaying the result of transforming the XML file to HTML. --  '*I was more interested in updating the content that displays on the page, not the actual XML document.*" That may be possible, but what will you do with the result?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I wanted to increase the number of Verification counts that appear on the page to users. So if the user clicks the "Yes" button, then the "Helpful" verification would increase by one (so it would display as 11 on the webpage, although the XML file still says 10). Does that make sense?

I'm ok that the number will reset each time the page is refreshed. This capability will simply serve as a demonstration of how it should work if the page was used an an actual page on the internet, and not just a local hard drive, which is where it currently lives.

Comment: "*I'm ok that the number will reset each time the page is refreshed.*" Then your question is really in the realm of HTML and Javascript. You only need XSLT to produce the right HTML code which, once rendered in a browser, will run on its own. FWIW, I've put together a small demo for you below, but I am no Javascript expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something you could use as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/best_answer">
    <html>
        <head>
            <script>
                function incrementValue(id)
                {
                    var element = document.getElementById(id);
                    element.innerHTML = parseInt(element.innerHTML) + 1
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
               <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">Was this topic helpful?</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <button onclick="incrementValue('positive')">Yes</button>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <button onclick="incrementValue('negative')">no</button>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Helpful</td>
                  <td>Unhelpful</td>
               </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="positive">
                        <xsl:value-of select="head/verifications/verification[@type='Helpful']"/>
                    </td>
                    <td id="negative">
                        <xsl:value-of select="head/verifications/verification[@type='Unhelpful']"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need! When I click on a button, the text area changes to NaN. According to a Google search, this stands for "Not a Number", which I assume appears because the original XML element is a text value, and not an actual number. Is this correct? Any suggestions on how to fix this issue? @michael.hor257k

Comment: "*Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?*" No, because I cannot reproduce the issue. The original XML element (verification) contains a numeric value (either 10 or 5). The Javascript function turns this into a number type, using the parseInt() function, before trying to add +1.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I was attempting to insert an image in the same cell that contains the number. Once I put the image in a different cell, it worked perfectly. Thanks for all your help!!